# The scala-tools Maven Repo Change: sbt Broken

Tags: scala, sbt

Yesterday, the Typesafe repo (at http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases) appeared to be down. Today, the page says it is being 'sunsetted' in favor of being served from Sonatype. Problem is that my just installed version of sbt (from homebrew on a mac) is still looking at the old repo and it's failing with:

```
[info] Resolving com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.0 ...
[warn] module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.0
```

Changing the repo URLs for the project is simple: found that in Build.scala. But that does me no good because the assembly jar not being found is coming up before the build of the project gets triggered (inferring this). Then I found this thread here about having to explode the jar.

Ok, I fixed this by getting a resolvers definition from the sbt-assembly github readme. However, my question is, why is 0.8.0 of sbt-assembly not on the new sonatype repo??

[New Releases Repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/)

Comment: Cause Eugene Yokota not pulled it to sonatype yet? IMO, it is too localized (specific moment in time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene simply hasn't pushed sbt-assembly up to Sonatype yet.  More importantly, you're running with an outdated version of SBT.  The Scala Tools hosting was never provided or supported by Typesafe.  Rather, it was a service provided to the community by David Pollak (the creator of Lift).  He has since decided to withdraw his involvement in the community, including the hosting for Scala Tools.  This is why the repository is in "sunset mode".  The latest versions of most Scala build tools (including SBT) no longer point to Scala Tools.

My advice would be to first upgrade to a newer version of SBT.  Second, file an issue on sbt-assembly prodding Eugene to take the necessary steps to get the project into Sonatype's repositories.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. If you have a minute, see my new question.

Comment: BTW, I did get this all working. I am surprised to hear my sbt is not the newest, I installed it with homebrew following the instructions from the readme file.

Comment: The latest release of SBT still references scala-tools.